# Independent and Dependent Variable Meaning?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology

Given a differential equation, for example:

> $\displaystyle \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + a \frac{dx}{dt} + kx = 0$

Is there a reason why we call $x$ the dependent variable and $t$ the independent variable? Here is the definition from my textbook:

> If an equation involves the derivative of one variable with respect to another, then the former is called a dependent variable and  the latter an independent variable

So according to this definition it makes sense why $x$ and $t$ are assigned in this way but is there an intuitive reasoning behind this terminology?

Comment: Ultimately the goal is to find an expression for $x$ in terms of $t$.  Hence, we want to know $x$ as $t$ varies.

Comment: The terminology comes from a time before the now standard language of **functions**. Functions became in principle dominant by the $20$-th century, but the ancient wording has hung on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is that $x$ is a function of $t$ --- $x$ *depends* on $t$ --- $t$ can be chosen arbitrarily (*independent* of anything else), and then the value of $x$ follows. This is for functions generally, not just for differential equations.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, $x$ is a function of $t$. Differential equations like these were normally studied in the context of science, so it would describe physical phenomena. One might want to measure "how does the pressure of a gas change when I vary its temperature?" To do that, you would vary your independent variable (temperature) and observe changes in the dependent variable (pressure). Pressure *depends* on temperature. This experiment gives you a function $P(T)$. The vocabulary for experiments carried on into functions.